# Which files under Magento webroot should be executable?

Tags: magento2, security, file-permissions, linux

Security best practices suggest that you should never have an executable in a public web directory. However, in a typical Magento install (in my very limited experience), this is not true.

Even in production, it seems `bin/magento` needs to remain executable. Are there other files that need to be executable?

Our setup is a Magento 2.3.3 store running on a dedicated (not shared) host. We have full root access and can create any users, groups and file permissions needed. We also have a filesystem that supports ACL's.

The site is under active development at this time.

Here are the executables under the Magento webroot. How many of these should we keep now? How many are needed in production?

```
find . -type f -executable
./vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer/run_phpcs.sh
./vendor/magento/zendframework1/bin/zf.bat
./vendor/magento/zendframework1/bin/zf.sh
./vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/bin/all-checks
./vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/bin/copyright-check
./vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/bin/mftf
./vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/bin/phpunit-checks
./vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/bin/static-checks
./vendor/composer/composer/bin/compile
./vendor/composer/composer/bin/composer
./vendor/seld/jsonlint/bin/jsonlint
./vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/bin/validate-json
./vendor/wikimedia/less.php/bin/lessc
./vendor/paragonie/random_compat/build-phar.sh
./vendor/yubico/u2flib-server/do-source-release.sh
./vendor/yubico/u2flib-server/examples/cli/u2f-server.phps
./vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/travis/download_and_run_es.sh
./vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/travis/generate_docs.sh
./vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/travis/run_es_docker.sh
./vendor/braintree/braintree_php/ci.sh
./vendor/tubalmartin/cssmin/cssmin
./vendor/tubalmartin/cssmin/tests/bin/runner
./vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcbf
./vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs
./vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs.bat
./vendor/grasmash/yaml-expander/scenarios/install
./vendor/consolidation/self-update/scripts/release
./vendor/sebastian/phpcpd/phpcpd
./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
./vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept
./vendor/behat/gherkin/bin/update_i18n
./vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/dev-tools/bin-download.sh
./vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/dev-tools/build.sh
./vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/dev-tools/check-shell-scripts.sh
./vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/dev-tools/trigger-website.sh
./vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer
./vendor/pdepend/pdepend/scripts/compare.sh
./vendor/pdepend/pdepend/src/bin/pdepend
./vendor/phpmd/phpmd/src/bin/phpmd
./bin/magento
```

Comment: Please read this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html.  Magento is served from pub/ in proper settings.

Comment: @BartZalas - Thank you. The tutorial addresses my security concerns. However, I need to know how to do that but still use a folder in the URL path like www.example.com/shop.

Comment: Please see my question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297386/how-to-change-url-of-magento-site-after-modifying-apache-documentroot